# appprodUrlGenerator not found in production enviroment

Tags: php, symfony

When I clear cache in my project on server I get this error:

`[Wed Feb 08 17:58:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'appprodUrlGenerator' not found in /home/hdc/www/app/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php on line 261`

And when I access the page I get this one:

`[Wed Feb 08 17:58:35 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'appprodUrlGenerator' not found in /home/hdc/www/app/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 1083`

I've tried almost everything I can think of: reinstall vendors, clear with/out debug, warmup, removing cache by hand.

Have anyone idea where it could came from or what problem it could be?

Comment: Need some more info. What server are you using and is the class something you wrote or something the app server uses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to warm your caches (which include a dumped container and a dumped router) in production by executing

```
php app/console --env=prod cache:warmup
```

Comment: This command is doing a bit more, since cache must be empty before warming up (according to documentation) - `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`